# How to use lsof, netstat and ps commands with complete options on Android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, linux, terminal, command-line

I tried T-ui and although it has the `lsof` command, it cannot do `lsof -i` for example, so I need to go through every single process in Android. My phone is rooted and I wanna know the PID of the process listening to a specific port. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Oh yeah, `netstat` command also don't allow any option, so if you guys know some terminal with the complete netstat command that would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard `lsof` source code has some differences with Android implementation. Android's own `/system/bin/lsof` or `/vendor/bin/lsof` (both provided by `toybox`) work perfectly, but with somewhat limited options.

However, to view listening ports, you have multiple options:

- `netstat` static binary compiled from standard source
- Netstat Plus app
- Netstat applet shipped with busybox (app or any standalone busybox) or the one that comes bundled with Android (at least on Android Pie, not sure about older versions); `/system/bin/netstat` or `/vendor/bin/netstat` (both provided by `toybox`) also offer enough options
- `ss` command; the Android one (standalone binary shipped at least with Pie) i.e. `/system/bin/ss` or static binary

To view processes:

- `ps` static binary compiled from standard source
- `ps` applet that comes bundled with Android; `/system/bin/ps` or `/vendor/bin/ps` (both provided by `toybox`) also offer enough options
- `ps` provided by Termux (procps-ng package) is a complete Linux ps